# Top-down 2D adventure game with plants and puzzles, that ran on Windows 9x

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing a certain game as a child. This was probably at least 15 years ago, but I suspect the game must be older. I think it might have been on Windows 95 or maybe Windows Me. It was some kind of 2D game with top-down view where you had to solve puzzles to progress. There were some sort of spiky fruits to collect and use as weapons against some fireball-spitting plants.

Also, I vividly remember there being flowerbeds (with a grid of flowers) that needed to be crossed on a special pattern – like only walk on the same color, or only the same shape. I think there were also some levels with swamp or poison stuff and needing to close valves or something.

It might have been DOS, but I think it was Windows 95. Also, it was mouse-controlled.

I sadly don't have any data, and the computer is long gone.

It was a bit like modern point-and-click adventure games; IIRC you could control your character kind of freely (I think there was an underlying grid).

The only real distinct part that I remember well are these riddles needing you to navigate flowerbeds (it was a grid of flowers, and you should only walk on the correct ones, forming a path to the other side), and also that there were some kind of spiky fruits to collect as weapons, and also some firespitting(?) red flesh-eating plants that dropped some kind of bomb when defeated.

I think there were also keys to collect, and maybe stuff like levers to unlock new areas. I think later levels also had valves to control a poison swamp or something.

Can anyone tell me the name of it from this poor description? I already tried Google, searching lists of games from Wikipedia, etc...

(Also cross-posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/vu6ur7/pclate_90s_maybe_puzzle_game_with_flower_puzzles/.)

Comment: Real-time or turn-based? Multiple lives? Score? Soundtrack? What did the player character look like?

Comment: I think it was real-time. I think it was more like an Adventure game where you could go between the areas ("levels") freely, so i don't remember any score.

Comment: Also, the plant riddles were only a part of the game. It is just one distinct part i remember very well.

Comment: @Boldar Please add all information to the question itself. mentioning them in comments is less useful.

Comment: Was there an inventory system? What did firing the weapon look like? Did it run windowed or fullscreen? (Are you sure it was a Windows game and not a DOS game?) I can’t say I have played many native PC top-down games (I mostly stuck to side-scrollers), but it may be of help for someone else.

Comment: I suggest asking in https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: @Boldar:  Do you and/or your family still have the computer on which you played the game (whether or not the computer can still start up)?  Alternatively, might y'all have a backup of that computer's hard drive somewhere (e.g. on an old external hard drive)?  Or might y'all still have a collection of old data CDs/DVDs which might also include the game?

Comment: I added the answers above

Comment: We've seen that if you can draw something just slightly resembling what the game look likes, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for linking the Reddit, i got help there already:
It was [Dr. Brain Thinking games - IQ Adventure](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dr-brain-thinking-games-iq-adventure)